# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word .doc/.docx lines count C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to count the total number of lines of the word document (.doc /.docx).

In my class, I added a reference to the COM library `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` through which I am counting the document's total word count.

With reference to the this [Lines.Count Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.lines.count?view=word-pia) documentation, the library also provides a lines count option in the latest version.

But unfortunately, I am unable to find the `Lines` interface or property in the whole library.
Is there any other way to get the total number of lines of the MS Word document as shown in the image below?

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3rFO.png)

**Method for words count (just for reference)**

```
public int GetWordsCountFromWordFile(string wordFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(wordFile))
            {
                var application = new Application();
                var document = application.Documents.Open(wordFile, ReadOnly: true);
                int count = document.Words.Count;
                document.Close();
                return count;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWriter.ErrorLogWriter(nameof(Client), nameof(TaskHelper), nameof(GetWordsCountFromWordFile), "int", ex.Message);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use the [`built in properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.builtindocumentproperties?view=word-pia), and get the `wdPropertyLines` to get Lines count.

Comment: Agree with @AnandSowmithiran. BTW the lines property you referenced is accessible through this path `document->windows->panes->pages->rectangles->lines`

Comment: @IliaMaskov I check but was unable to get panes after `document->windows`. Note: I assume that the `document` referred to here is the same document variable in my code in the question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I found the easiest and shortest working solution to the problem, exactly like I wanted it.

I added up two more lines of code in the method provided in my question and I got accurate results.

```
int lines = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticLines, true);
application.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
```

**Note:**

> Sending true parameter in *ComputeStatistics* method to include footnotes and endnotes.
>
> Quit will stop the *save changes window* from opening and will close the MS Word process running in the background.

Comment: I hope this answer will help many developers if they are facing the same issue or looking for some similar solutions.